# Probability space with pairwise disjoint sets

Tags: probability

I asked myself, if there is a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ such we can find pairwise disjoint sets $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in\mathcal{F}$ with $P(A_n)=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, but I couldn't find an example. My Questions is if such a space exists or not?

Comment: I may be missing something, but the answer seems trivial.  Example: coin with both sides the same (heads).  Let $A_n)$ be the outcome of the nth flip $P(An=\ heads)=1$.  The $A_n$ are disjoint.

Comment: On the other hand, if all these events are on the same probability space, being disjoint means that the probability of union= sum of probabilities, but the sum cannot exceed 1 on a probability space, so you can have only 1 element.

Comment: @herbsteinberg - I prefer your second comment.  In your first, the $A_n$ are *independent* in the sense that $P(A_m \cap A_n) = P(A_m)P(A_n)$, but they are not *disjoint* since $P(A_m \cap A_n) \not = 0$